# Changing a wide data set to a long data set in SAS

Tags: sas

I've looked at a handful of other similar questions (here, here, and here), but have not had success with the accepted answers I found.  I'm trying to transform a wide data set into a long data set, turning column names into rows with matching records adjacent to the old column names.  I can't seem to get the original column names to appear using my current code.

I have a wide dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this:
[image]

I've tried to do this with an array:

```
data want;
set have;
array d ImprovementPlan -- AssessmentPlan;
do i = 1 to dim(d);
    Section = d{i};
        Text = d
    output;
    end;
keep DBN Emp_ID FiscalYear Section Text Meeting1    Meeting2    Meeting3    Meeting4    Meeting5; 
run;
```

But end up with this:
 [image]

I appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: First, you should post your actual data so someone can copy and paste it into a sas program.  That said, what you want to do can easily be done using proc transpose.  Post your data and I'll provide a workable solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able make PROC TRANSPOSE work using the following code:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.t_yoy
    OUT=flash.TTRANSPOSED_yoy(LABEL="Transposed WORK.T2017")
    PREFIX=Text
    NAME=Section
    LABEL=Label
;
BY Emp_ID FiscalYear DBN;
    VAR ImprovementPlan ActionPlan TimeLinePlan SupportPlan AssessmentPlan;
    COPY DBN Emp_ID FiscalYear Meeting1 Meeting2 Meeting3 Meeting4 Meeting5;

RUN; QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

`union` in proc SQL should do the trick

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select DBN, Emp_ID, FiscalYear, 'Action_Plan' as Section, Action_Plan as Text, Meeting1, Meeting2, Meeting3, Meeting4, Meeting5
  from have
  union
  select DBN, Emp_ID, FiscalYear, 'Timeline' as Section, Timeline as Text, Meeting1, Meeting2, Meeting3, Meeting4, Meeting5
  from have
  union
  select DBN, Emp_ID, FiscalYear, 'Support_Plan' as Section, Support_Plan as Text, Meeting1, Meeting2, Meeting3, Meeting4, Meeting5
  from have
  union
  select DBN, Emp_ID, FiscalYear, 'Assessment_Plan' as Section, Assessment_Plan as Text, Meeting1, Meeting2, Meeting3, Meeting4, Meeting5
  from have
  ;
quit;
```

SAS also has `proc transpose` to do that kind of operation.

EDIT: something in the lines of

```
proc sort data=have;
  by DBN Emp_ID FiscalYear Meeting1 Meeting2 Meeting3 Meeting4 Meeting5;
run;    
proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(column1=Text)) name=Section prefix=column;
  by DBN Emp_ID FiscalYear Meeting1 Meeting2 Meeting3 Meeting4 Meeting5;
  var action_plan timeline support_plan assessment_plan;
run;
```

Comment: use proc transpose instead

Comment: @DCR I did suggest that in my answer. However I don't use it enough to just know of the top of my head how to write it for his purposes. And lacking sample code that I can just copy-paste to SAS and have a try, I don't have time...

Comment: and so you did!

Comment: @DCR happy?  ;-)